# FlatMap gives warning with Int type array but not with String type array

Tags: ios, swift, flatmap

When I use `flatMap` with `String` type array it didn't give any warning, while it gives warning in case of `Int` type array. Why? Example:

```
let strings = [
    "I'm excited about #SwiftUI",
    "#Combine looks cool too",
    "This year's #WWDC was amazing"
]
strings.flatMap{$0 + "."} //No warning

let ints = [
   2,3,4
]
ints.flatMap{$0 + 1} //'flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value
```

Comment: `String` is `Sequence`, `Int` is not.

Answer (score 8):

It is because these are two different `flatMap` methods.

So, before I answer your question, let’s step back and consider what [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap) is now intended to do, namely, applying transform to a sequence and concatenating the resulting sequences. The typical example is used for “flattening” arrays of arrays):

```
let arrayOfArrays = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
let array = arrayOfArrays.flatMap { $0 }
print(array)
```

Resulting in:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

The `flatMap` has flattened the array of arrays to a single array.

Confusingly, there was another, now deprecated, [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126949-flatmap) that would perform the transform, unwrapping optional results in a sequence or collection, but removing those that were `nil`. Fortunately, that has now been renamed to [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) to avoid confusion. So, this is why you got your warning.

Consider:

```
let input: [Int?] = [0, 1, nil, 3]
let results = input.flatMap { $0 } // 'flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value
print(results)
```

Resulting in:

> [0, 1, 3]

So, we should replace `flatMap` with `compactMap`, as advised:

```
let input: [Int?] = [0, 1, nil, 3]
let results = input.compactMap { $0 }
print(results)
```

That will give us the desired results, without the warning.

---

So, let’s go back to your examples. Because strings are arrays of characters, it will take you at your word and flatten that down:

```
let strings = [
    "I'm excited about #SwiftUI",
    "#Combine looks cool too",
    "This year's #WWDC was amazing"
]
let stringResults = strings.flatMap { $0 + "." }
print(stringResults)
```

The result of that is a flattened array of characters:

> ["I", "\'", "m", " ", "e", "x", "c", "i", "t", "e", "d", " ", "a", "b", "o", "u", "t", " ", "#", "S", "w", "i", "f", "t", "U", "I", ".", "#", "C", "o", "m", "b", "i", "n", "e", " ", "l", "o", "o", "k", "s", " ", "c", "o", "o", "l", " ", "t", "o", "o", ".", "T", "h", "i", "s", " ", "y", "e", "a", "r", "\'", "s", " ", "#", "W", "W", "D", "C", " ", "w", "a", "s", " ", "a", "m", "a", "z", "i", "n", "g", "."]

That obviously not what you intended, but the compiler took you at your word that you wanted to flatten the array of array of characters (i.e. the array of strings) into a flat array of characters. So that’s why there was no warning.

---

Needless to say, in your examples, you would use neither `flatMap` (because you aren’t dealing with arrays of arrays) nor `compactMap` (because you aren’t dealing with optionals). You’d just use `map`:

```
let strings = [
    "I'm excited about #SwiftUI",
    "#Combine looks cool too",
    "This year's #WWDC was amazing"
]
let stringsResults = strings.map { $0 + "." }
print(stringsResults)

let ints = [2, 3, 4]
let intsResults = ints.map { $0 + 1 }
print(intsResults)
```

---

Completely unrelated, but in the interest of full disclosure (but at the risk of making it even more confusing), there is actually yet *another* [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) method (!), one on the `Optional` type. Admittedly, this is arguable used less commonly than the array flattening (i.e. sequence concatenating) rendition, but I should probably acknowledge its existence.

This `flatMap` method on `Optional` “Evaluates the given closure when this `Optional` instance is not `nil`, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.” But if the optional was `nil`, this `flatMap` will return `nil`, too.

For example:

```
func message(for value: Int?) -> String? {
    return value.flatMap { "The value is \($0)" }
}
```

Thus, if `value` was `42`, result would be the optional string, `"The value is 42"`. But if `value` was `nil`, then result will be `nil`.

This rendition of `flatMap` is not relevant to the question at hand, but I wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness.